# Google maps Places in radius for android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I try to bring a circle around a central point on kakrte google / 
I have a point of lat and LNG center point.

1. Can not understand how you can get a point on the left side
2. Or how to calculate the formula radius depending on rastoyaniyaot land. (Zoom)

screenshot:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to draw a blue circle around my center point. There's a 1.5 kilometer radius to it.

```
final float NEARBY_CONTACTS_RADIUS  = 1.5f;

CircleOptions co = new CircleOptions();

        co.center(new LatLng(myPosition[0], myPosition[1]));
        co.radius(NEARBY_CONTACTS_RADIUS * 1000);
        co.strokeColor(mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.map_blue));
        co.fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mCircle = map.addCircle(co);
```

myPosition is your center point.

NEARBY_CONTACTS_RADIUS is a float with value = 1.5f representing 1.5 kilometers.

I know this is not the exact answer of your question but maybe will give you an idea. Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that. I need to at least know how to get the coordinates of the picture under paragraph 3. 
Or if imeitsya formula for calculating how much is included in one pixel coordinates. how much is offset such as zoom = 14